# JavaScript: JQuery doesn't apply the css after ajax call completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a requirement where I am populating a json object array using an ajax call in my javascript, and then displaying the array in my html as a table. Also, based on some Rank column in my table data returned in the ajax call, I need to change the background color of the column cells that displays the Rank column. So I want some first 10 Ranks to have green background color of the cells containing those Rank values, next 10 as yellow, and so on.

While I am trying to achieve this, I am facing a situation with my code, and not able to find the reason.

My code looks like this:

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
   async:true,
   url: ...
   data: {
       format: 'json'
   },
   success: function(forecast) {
       // put the forecast data inside the array
   }
   type: 'GET',
   complete: function(){
       columnTh = $("#forecastTable th:contains('Rank')");
       console.log("columnTh:: " + columnTh.index()); //prints 1, the position of Rank column
       columnIndex = columnTh.index();
       $('#forecastTable tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').css("background-color", "blue");
   }
   ....
   ....
```

This doesn't change the background color of the table cell for the Rank column to blue! I changed it to "color", "blue" also, but that didn't work either. But in the same complete function, if I put a code like the one below, it does change the color of the header text to green for the table header:

```
columnThAll = $("#forecastTable th");
columnThAll.css("color", "green");
```

Can you please let me know what should be changed to set the background color of the table cells, the way I am trying to do above, based on the jquery result fetch.

Comment: can you tell what error message you are getting. by inspecting in DOM or in console.

Comment: Hi Niraj, I am not getting any error either in my console log. Just that it doesn't set the color.

Comment: i think you should console log this $('#forecastTable tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')') and see whether you are able to select the correct rank. you can console log this when page is loaded directly in dom also.

Comment: Hi Niraj, thanks for the input. I have printed the value of $('#forecastTable tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')'), and it shows as: [object Object]. I also have printed the values of the object as: Object.values($('#forecastTable tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')')), and it shows as: [object HTMLTableCellElement],1,[object Object].

Comment: can you reproduce your example at jsfiddle ??

Comment: Hi Niraj, I could do it at last. In my ajax complete function, I was calling the function directly that sets the color. Also, it was an async call, and so the table structure was getting loaded and data was yet to be loaded. So the set color was not working. I then called the set color function within the complete with a timeout as below:

setTimeout(function(){self.colorRank()},50);

this worked well, and it then set the colors properly. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: The way you did is hacky solution. go with it if you have no alternative, but read for done method of ajax call.